# Finding ESS in pure and mixed strategies

Tags: game-theory, evolutionary-game-theory

I have to find all the ESS(pure and mixed, in this game)

$\left(
    \begin{array}{c|ccc}
        & A &  B &  C\\
\hline
    A &0,0& 3,1 &0,0\\
    B &1,3& 0,0 &0,0\\
    C &0,0& 0,0 &1,1  
    \end{array}
\right)$

It's easy to see that C is the pure ESS, but I can't find the mixed ESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mixed ESS plays $A$ with probability $3/4$ and $B$ with probability $1/4$.

Comment: Can you explain your answer please?

Comment: Looking at the $0$'s in the bimatrix, one can see that $\{A,B\}\times \{A,B\}$ and $\{C\} \times \{C\}$ are both evolutionarily stable sets. So I computed the mixed strategy equilibrium with support in $\{A,B\}\times \{A,B\}$ .